# Mail Gateway / Antispam for Linux Ubuntu Server

Tags: mail, antivirus, spamassassin

I have recently install a mail server without AV/AS built-in.
Whats your offer to install with **Ubuntu server**.
please note that its Server version and "**I haven't graphical environment**".
can it be possible to have one powerful AV/AS that automatically update virus list and check for income/outcome email for virus and spam?
I also hear about clamAV. however ComdoAV for win because of needing graphical environment didn't be seen good enough.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu offers a choice of SMTP (email) servers. My preference is Exim4, but others prefer Postfix.  Both of these integrate with spamassaassin (for spam filtering) and clamav (for virus scanning).  Clamav regularly downloads updates, and spamassassin has rule database feeds.

I am not sure what you mean by "ComdoAV for win because of needing graphical environment".  A fully functional email server can be run on the Ubuntu server version which does not have a graphical environment.  There are various graphic packages that can be installed if desired.

In today's environment, setting up the software is the easy part.  Getting appropriate connectivity (static IP address), and setting up the various resources in DNS takes a bit of work.  See the canonical answers on ServerFault such a https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user?s=3|0.2216

Comment: Thank you bill for your valuable information. Actually Comodo AV installed in ubuntu server but im really afraid that all of components works fine. it exactly because of graphical issue that you mentioned it before. Thanks again. you help me much.